# Using the window resize function to keep variables uptodate?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am a little confused on how to keep some variables Ive created uptodate when the window is resized so my scroll function carries on getting the correct values. Basically I have multiple elements that contain a message that gets displayed when the user scrolls the element into 50% height of the viewport height. This works fine but my issue is when I resize I'm not sure how to update my variables `boxHeight, elementOffset, verticalMatch` which keep control of the values I need to use in my scroll event. I was wondering can someone help explain how I can resolve this?

My code looks like this

```
 var windowHeight = $(window).height(),
    headerHeight = $('.header').height();

$('.box').each(function (i,e) { 

    var el = $(e);

    var boxHeight = el.height(),
        elementOffset = el.offset().top,
        verticalMatch = (windowHeight / 2) + (headerHeight / 2) - (boxHeight / 2);

    $(window).on('scroll', function () {
        var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop(),
            distance = elementOffset - scrollTop;

        if( distance <= verticalMatch ) {
           el.addClass('is-active');
        }       

    });
});


$(window).on('resize', function() {
    windowHeight = $(window).height()
    elementOffset = $('.box').offset().top;

    $('.box').each(function (i,e) { 

        var el = $(e);

        //update boxHeight, elementOffset, verticalMatch
        verticalMatch = (windowHeight / 2) + (headerHeight / 2) - (boxHeight / 2);
    });
});
```

And heres the JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fm4z7/2/

If someone could explain how I do this it would be great!

Comment: How about just updating their values with simple assignment statements? (Your "scroll" handler doesn't pay attention to the "windowHeight" variable anyway.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you want to do is update your sizing variables during a resize event, then do just that:

```
$(window).on('resize', function() {
    windowHeight = $(window).height();
    elementOffset = $('.box').offset().top;
});
```

Your variables are global so they can be accessed anywhere.

Comment: sorry ive overlooked my verticalMatch variable, how do I keep this calculation uptodate?

Comment: @styler just set it again like you do in the original declaration.

Comment: @Lochemage ok thanks, I have one more issue I was hoping you could help with, I want to set the script up so I have multiple elements that appear individually when the box matches the verticalMatch, my problem is with the resize function as this time my variables aren't global. Can you advise how I can fix this one? http://jsfiddle.net/fm4z7/2/

Comment: Here's a new http://jsfiddle.net/fm4z7/3/.  I've changed your code quite a bit but the basics are:  I now store individual element data as part of that elemens jquery `data()` instead of my own var and I've moved the scroll event handler to be a single event instead of one for each box.  The fiddle also has comments of what I'm doing.

Comment: this looks perfect, thanks for much for all the commented code and help!!