# KineticJS, Veeery slow click event on image

Tags: javascript, mouseevent, kineticjs

I want to click some KineticJS images that is marked with pencircle on the picture:

[image: picture of webpage]

The picture with blue circle is working okey.

The picture with yellow circle is working every 50 clicks.

The pictures with red circle is never working.

This is how I add the eventlisteners:

Blue:

```
    var imgLogo = new Image();
    imgLogo.src = 'http://folk.ntnu.no/rubenra/web/Resources/bobsByggLogo.png';
    imgLogo.onload = function(){
        imageLogo = new Kinetic.Image({
            image: imgLogo,
            x: 10,
            y: 580
        });
        layer.add(imageLogo);
        imageLogo.on('mousedown', function() {
            console.log('logo trykt');
        });
    }
```

Yellow:

```
    var imgNextDayButton = new Image();
    imgNextDayButton.src = 'http://folk.ntnu.no/rubenra/web/Resources/nextDayButton.png';
    imgNextDayButton.onload = function(){
        imageNextDayButton = new Kinetic.Image({
            image: imgNextDayButton,
            x: buttonsBound.getAttr('x')+60,
            y: buttonsBound.getAttr('y')+20
        });

        imageNextDayButton.on('mousedown', function() {
            alert('Neste Dag');
            console.log('knapp trykt');
        });

        layer.add(imageNextDayButton);


    }
```

Red:

```
    var imgWarn = new Image();
    imgWarn.src = 'http://folk.ntnu.no/rubenra/web/Resources/shapeWarn.png';
    imgWarn.onload = function(){
        imageWarn = new Kinetic.Image({
            image: imgWarn,
            x: xstart+100,
            y: ystart+45,
            width: imgWarn.width,
            heigth: imgWarn.height
        });
        imageWarn.on('mousedown',function(){
            alert('Show Warning to ' + name);
        })
        group.add(imageWarn);
    }
```

And here is link to the [sourcecode](http://jsbin.com/nazikiru/1/edit?html,console,output). It is not working on jsbin, but it should work in every code editor.

Link to the page on server:
[Page on server](http://folk.ntnu.no/rubenra/web/index.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Yechoua Guedj was right that it was because of the way I resized my canvas. A simple way that solved all my eventproblems is like this.

```
window.onresize = function () {
        var width = $("#fullscreenDiv").innerWidth();
        var height = width * 9 / 16;
        xScale = (width/initialWidth)*initialScale.x;
        var newScale = {x: xScale, y: xScale};
        stage.setAttr('width', width);
        stage.setAttr('height', height);
        stage.setAttr('scale', newScale);
        stage.draw();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

tried your page on server, and i just found that the code work fine.
here some logs that show up when I clicked on some elements:

```
start: 147 index.html:361
stopp index.html:377
start: 391 index.html:361
stopp index.html:377
start: 77 index.html:361
stopp index.html:377
start: 840 index.html:361
stopp index.html:377
start: 573 index.html:361
stopp index.html:377
start: 439 index.html:361
stopp index.html:377
start: 503 index.html:361
stopp index.html:377
start: 354 index.html:361
stopp index.html:377
start: 362 index.html:361
stopp index.html:377
start: 585 index.html:361
stopp index.html:377
start: 525 index.html:361
stopp
```

i've tried it with chromium did you solve your problem already?

dude your code work fine:

```
- for the yellow: ok
- for the red: click on the warn logo (I can drag your worker where I whant, think to fix it)
- for the blue click on him where you whant
```

it'll work fine only
   if you didn't show the console or resize the page (let it on full screen), here my teste: downloaded the whole script (and your xml) on my local server, tested it with console oppenend, clicking everywhere and then, find out that a warning is catched under a worker
   (like x+40 and y-60) so i searched on the code if something's wrong, found nothing, retryed the same without the console just to see if it's the same, and guess
   what? all work fine for me. (you have to work   with offset value
   instead of absolute ;) )

Comment: Well, this is just the log for the event when you click above the statuspart. If you click and then move the mouse, the boxes will move. I also have a console.log line for clicking the images I described, but they never occure.

Comment: Great. Yeah now I see that if I scale the browser to the values I use to draw the stage, everything work as I should. But how do I use offset values? I know when using absolute values, the top leftcorner equals (0,0) and then I just add values to place top leftcorner on the screen.

Comment: you can see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18131667/using-the-window-resize-function-to-keep-variables-uptodate the question already have an answer ;)

Comment: I can't see how that answer fitts my situation, because they have similar html IDs, but I guess I need to loop trough my layer childrens and set this offset thing. Maybe you can explain a bit more what this offset is, and give me some code? Or maybe see my resizecanvas function in the code?

Comment: your problem come form here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19964591/how-to-get-canvas-in-fullscreen-mode-with-kineticjs you've grabbed this code without searching if it fit for you, [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17468180/kineticjs-scaling-stage-to-viewport[/link] is more specific for you ;), don't forget to read and test the jsfiddle ;)